# Can I hide a branch in a git repo for all remote clones?

Tags: git, deployment, remote-access

I have a central repository at `server` and local repos at `local`. In the `server` repo there is a branch `live`, that pulls from `master` sometimes, adds some modifications and is then used to update a service.

The `live` branch of `server` is of no interest for the users in their `local` repositories. They should not see it nor be able to fetch it / push to it, in short, interact with it in any way.

Is there any way in Git to allow such a behaviour: Prevent a branch of `server` from being listed in the `local` repositories?

```
local$ git remote add server example.com
local$ git fetch server
local$ git branch --remotes
server/foo
server/live     # <-- don't show this branch
server/master
```

A solution on `server` would be preferred. But as of now, since there is no untrusted committer at the moment, solutions just hiding the `live` branch via config in `local` repos would work, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: as of git 1.8.2, git supports `transfer.hiderefs` (spelled `transfer.hideRefs` in [the git config documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html)).  It was somewhat buggy until git 2.3.5 / 2.4.0 (as in, avoid it if you allow smart-http transfer, until you have 2.3.5 or 2.4.0 installed on the server).

To hide server/live:

```
git config --add transfer.hiderefs refs/heads/server/live
```

This is not perfect hiding: it exposes the existence of the name to push probes (as does `receive.hiderefs`).  See also `uploadpack.allowTipSHA1InWant`.

<s>No: the standard git remote protocols allow incoming querents to see *all* references.  (You could fake it by removing the reference while serving clients, then re-inserting it, but you'd have to avoid any garbage collections from running if that is the only reference to the commit in question, and of course the reference would be unavailable to your own code at that time as well.  It would be simpler to just clone the repo, and then remove the ref and serve from the "de-live-d" clone.  Equivalently, but even simpler and probably faster, use a different repo to hold the "live" branch in the first place—that repo can fetch from the shared one as usual, but have its own private "live" branch.)</s>

You can prevent someone or anyone from *updating* any references you like, through the usual pre-receive and update hooks.  But any reference you have, someone else can see.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had the idea of a second repo already. And it might be quite cheap storage-wise thanks to hard links. The idea of blocking commits via hooks might be easier to implement right now (quick-n-dirty, but does the trick), though.